# How to set the number of ticks and labels of pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way that I can divide an axis to a certain number of ticks and then label them? For example, I have the following plot and I want to have 4 ticks on the x axis and be able to set the labels myself.

[image]

and here's what I want to achieve (please note that the two plots are the same):

[image]

and this is the script I am using to create the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I can divide the axis using this: `plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=4)`, but I could not set the labels myself.

Comment: do you mean you want to set the numbers on the "ruler" ? i mean, you want to set these numbers: `0`, `0.5`, `1`, `1.5` on the axis?

Comment: I think so. Exactly like the red plot. (the plot are the same abd are contructed with the same data. Just rulers are different.

Comment: try this: `plt.yticks(np.arange(-1, 1.25, 0.25))` and `plt.xticks(np.arange(-1, 1.25, 0.25))`

Comment: It doesn't work: `plt.xticks(np.arange(-1, 1.25, 0.25))` just shows `-1 to 1` on the left side of x axis of the blue plot with its original ruler.

Comment: You need to use `imshow`'s `extent` argument. I guess there are enough question and answers on that matter once you know what to look for.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the use of `extent` in my case?@ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest mentioned, using `imshow`'s `extent` was the answer:

```
plt.imshow(data, extent=[0,1.5,3,0], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```